# Angular js function logic and repetition error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm having a logic error with my code using angular js. What I have done is made a function that loops through a json array and returns the strings of the weather condition, eg
'clear',
'cloudy', etc...
It then checks to see if the value of the string is equal to another string. If it is, it returns an image link associated with the weather condition. The problem is that html ng-repeat function is repeating that one image and not any other image.
Here is the js:

```
    var app=angular.module('app');
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
       $scope.currentSydney = null;
      $scope.currentMelbourne = null;
      $scope.currentAdelaide = null;
       $scope.currentDarwin = null;
        $scope.currentBrisbane = null;
          $scope.currentMelbourne = null;
            $scope.currentCairns = null;
        $http.jsonp('http://api.wunderground.com/api/5ad0204df4bdbeff/conditions/q/Australia/Melbourne.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){

         $scope.currentMelbourne=data;



      });
       $http.jsonp('http://api.wunderground.com/api/5ad0204df4bdbeff/conditions/q/Australia/Sydney.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){

         $scope.currentSydney=data;



      });

        $http.jsonp('http://api.wunderground.com/api/5ad0204df4bdbeff/conditions/q/Australia/Adelaide.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){

         $scope.currentAdelaide=data;



      });
        $http.jsonp('http://api.wunderground.com/api/5ad0204df4bdbeff/conditions/q/Australia/Darwin.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){

         $scope.currentDarwin=data;



      });

         $http.jsonp('http://api.wunderground.com/api/5ad0204df4bdbeff/conditions/q/Australia/Perth.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){

         $scope.currentPerth=data;



      });

        $http.jsonp('http://api.wunderground.com/api/5ad0204df4bdbeff/conditions/q/Australia/Cairns.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){

        $scope.currentCairns=data;



      });


      $http.jsonp('http://api.wunderground.com/api/5ad0204df4bdbeff/conditions/q/Australia/Brisbane.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){


         $scope.currentBrisbane=data;
         $scope.cityData=[
         {  name:'Brisbane',
            temp:$scope.currentBrisbane.current_observation.temp_c,  
            image:$scope.currentBrisbane.current_observation.icon
            },               

          { name:'Melbourne',
             temp:$scope.currentMelbourne.current_observation.temp_c,  
              image:$scope.currentMelbourne.current_observation.icon

            },

         { 
            name:'Adelaide',
            temp:$scope.currentAdelaide.current_observation.temp_c ,  
            image:$scope.currentAdelaide.current_observation.icon


          },

         {  name:'Darwin',
             temp:$scope.currentDarwin.current_observation.temp_c  ,
            image:$scope.currentDarwin.current_observation.icon


          },

         {  name:'Perth',
             temp:$scope.currentPerth.current_observation.temp_c  ,
             image:$scope.currentPerth.current_observation.icon

         },

         {  name:'Cairns',

            temp:$scope.currentCairns.current_observation.temp_c,  
            image:$scope.currentCairns.current_observation.icon

        },
         ]
     for(y = 0 ; y < 6; y++){


            var string = $scope.cityData[y].image;

            console.log(string[10]);
}

      });



      $scope.iconString = function() {
        switch ($scope.currentSydney.current_observation.icon) {
          case 'partlycloudy' :
            return 'pics/partlycloudy.png';
          case 'clear' :   
          return 'pics/partlycloudy.png';

        }
      }

      $scope.repeat = function() {

         for(y = 0 ; y < 1; y++){



            var string = $scope.cityData[y].image;

            if(string=='mostlycloudy'){
             return 'pics/mostlycloudy.png';

            } 


         }





        }









    });
```

And here is the html:

```
        <div id="weather-container">

        <div id="current-weather">
            <!--Angular JSON pull -->
            <div id="title"><span id="current-title">Current Weather</span></div>
            <div id="current-condition">{{currentSydney.current_observation.weather}}</div>

             <img ng-src="{{iconString()}}"></img>
            <div id="current-temp"><span id="current-temp"> {{currentSydney.current_observation.temp_c}} </span></div>
            <span id="current-city">{{currentSydney.current_observation.display_location.city}} </span>
        </div>






            <!--Angular JSON pull and iteration-->
        <div id="other-city-container">
            <div class="other-city-weather" ng-repeat="city in cityData" >
                <!--Image-->
             <img ng-src="{{repeat()}}"></img>
            <div class="current-city-temp">
                <span>{{city.temp}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="current-city-lower">
                <span>{{city.name}}</span>
            </div>
            </div>


        </div>


    </div>
```

Now I'm calling the repeat function in the html inside the img src tag.

`

Comment: What do you expect from : <img ng-src="{{repeat()}}"></img>

Comment: I mean, what should repeat() do ?

Comment: Basically repeat() returns a path to an image when the function is run ng-src allows this to happen. The only problem is its repeating the image for the first condition that is true for all of the divs that get created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see. You are making 2 loops : ng-repeat in the view, and a for loop in the controller ( repeat() ).

But I think that right now, **they are not related to each other** (which is what you need I guess): **getting the index of the ng-repeat loop in your repeat method**.

Try something like that :

In the view :

```
<img ng-src="{{repeat($index)}}" /><!-- Getting the current $index of the ng-repeat loop and passing it to the $scope.repeat() method -->
```

In the controller :

```
$scope.repeat = function(index) { // there, index becomes the value we just put in the view ($index = the current index of the ng-repeat loop), e.g. : 0,1,2,3...


        var string = $scope.cityData[index].image; // We go get the right city in the cityData array, according to the current ng-repeat index.

        // then we do the job
        if(string=='mostlycloudy'){
         return 'pics/mostlycloudy.png';

        } 


     }
```

Not sure that works as I didn't test it, but you may know what I mean ?

Comment: It works thanks so much is there a way you could explain the code for next time?

Comment: I will edit my answer and put some note on the code. Feel free to mark it as resolved if so.

Comment: I have another question similar to this one if you can answer it that would be great

Comment: So make another thread and give me a link so I can answer it if I can.